# an agent and three nervous people - java multithreading problem

Tags: java, multithreading

There is one agent and three nervous people. The agent possesses three necessary reserves - items for the treatment of nervousness: paper, toy and food. One of the people has endless supplies of paper, another of toys and a third of a food. The agent starts by putting two different objects on the table, one at a time. A person to whom those two objects are missing, he takes them, uses them and stops being nervous. He then informs agent that he has finished, and the agent then puts two new items on the table, etc.

This is my approach: I started with making a class Person that extends Thread, so I will have 3 threads at the end. Then I have a Resource class with three booleans for each of the three objects that refers to if the object is taken. I randomly chose two of them to be free, is that okay, since I didn't know how else to do it?

The problem is when I start the program, two threads take objects at the same time, which is not good. I really don't know where is the mistake..

Here is the code:

```
public class Person extends Thread{
    int id;
    String s; //1/3 
    Resource r;
    
    public Person(int id, String s, Resource r) {
        this.id = id;
        this.s = s;
        this.r = r;
    }
    
    public void enjoys() {
        try {
            sleep(3000);
            System.out.println("Person " +this.id+ " is enjoying.");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            r.takesResource(this.s);
            enjoys();
            r._signal(this.s);
        }
    }   
}
```

```
public class Resource {
    boolean p = false; //paper
    boolean t = false; //toy
    boolean f = true; //food
    
    public synchronized void takesResource(String s) {
        
        if (s.compareTo("paper")==0) {
            while(this.t==true && this.f==true) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Person that has paper waits for food and toy");
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            this.t = true;
            this.f = true;
            System.out.println("Person "+((Person)Thread.currentThread()).id +" takes toy and food");
            
        } else if (s.compareTo("toy")==0) {
            while(this.f==true && this.p==true) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Person that has toy waits for food and paper");
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            this.p = true;
            this.f = true;
            System.out.println("Person "+((Person)Thread.currentThread()).id +" took paper and food");   
        } else if (s.compareTo("food")==0) {
            while(this.t==true && this.p==true) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Person that has food waits for paper and toy");
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            this.t = true;
            this.p = true;
            System.out.println("Person "+((Person)Thread.currentThread()).id +" takes toy and paper");
            
        }
    }
    
    public synchronized void _signal(String s) {
        if (s.compareTo("paper")==0) {
            this.t = false;
            this.f = false;
            System.out.println("Person "+((Person)Thread.currentThread()).id +" frees toy and food");
        } else if (s.compareTo("toy")==0) {
            this.f = false;
            this.p = false;
            System.out.println("Person "+((Person)Thread.currentThread()).id +" frees paper and food");
        } else if (s.compareTo("food")==0) {
            this.t = false;
            this.p = false;
            System.out.println("Person "+((Person)Thread.currentThread()).id +" frees toy and paper");
        }
        notifyAll();
    }
}
```

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Resource r = new Resource();
        Person p1 = new Person(1,"paper",r);
        Person p2 = new Person(2,"toy",r);
        Person p3 = new Person(3,"food",r);
        
        p1.start();
        p2.start();
        p3.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is when I start the program, two threads take objects at the same time, which is not good. I really don't know where is the mistake..

1. One problem is that you `while` tests should be a || not an &&.  You want to sleep until *both* of the resources that you need are available.
2. You initialize the `food` to the `true` which I don't think you meant to do.

Running this a few number of iterations makes it seem like the algorithm is not fair and one thread always gets the resources or it alternates but this is only due to race conditions.  If you change the enjoy sleep to (let's say) 1ms, and run this 100000s of times you should see all 3 threads get similar number of resource "enjoyment".

```
long enjoyCount;
...
// enjoy sleep
Thread.sleep(1);
enjoyCount++;
if (enjoyCount % 1000 == 0) {
    System.out.println("Person " + id + " enjoyed " + enjoyCount);
}
```

The thread that notified and released the lock tends to reacquire the lock because of race conditions so adding in a `Thread.sleep(1);` call at the top of the `run()` loop gives more cycles to other threads.

Here's my [final working code](https://pastebin.com/3FN8D2ej).

A couple other comments about your code:

- Don't use single character variables.  `paper` is much better than `p`.  You wouldn't have to add comments like `// food` if the variable was named `food`;
- With threads, a better pattern is for sometime to implement `Runnable` as opposed to extending `Thread`.
- Never do `if (paper == true)` (or `false` for that matter).  You should say `if (paper)` (and `if (! paper)`).
- `s.compareTo("paper") == 0` should be changed to `resourceName.equals("paper")`.
- `((Person) Thread.currentThread()).id` is a strange pattern.  I'd either pass in the `Person` or use the internal thread-id `Thread.currentThread().getId()`.
- `_signal` is a strange method name.  `signal` is fine.
- The typical pattern is to only use `this` in constructor or setters.  Typical IDEs colorize the field names so using it everywhere isn't necessary.  Better (i.e. longer) field names would make this more apparent.
- In these threaded programs, be careful about `System.out.println(...)` because it is a `PrintStream` which is a synchronous class.  That means that additional locking is going on which may affect your programs behavior.

Comment: Oh, I see.. Now that I have fixed the while loop, only one thread gets to enjoy, the other two are constantly waiting.. Do you have an idea how to solve that? Or maybe my approach isn't quite good in general :/